# Transferring at Zürich Airport do I need to go through Passport Control or only Security?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, short-connections, zrh

I am arriving at Zurich airport from Hong Kong and then going on to Copenhagen with a 55 minute transfer time, flying Swissair.

Do I need to go through passport control at Zurich or only go through Security check?

Comment: You will have to go through passport control at either Zurich or Copenhagen, and since they are both within the Schengen area there shouldn't be any practical difference for you.

Comment: @GregHewgill There is a very practical difference: The OP will have to go through passport control in Zurich since the second flight is an intra-Schengen flight.

Answer (score 7):

Because you are entering the Schengen area in Zurich, you will go through passport control here. But you will *not* go through customs.

As soon as you pass through passport controls in Zurich, you will be at the Skymetro. Take it over to your departure terminal (e.g. A/B), visit your airline's check in desk if you don't already have your boarding pass for Copenhagen, then go through security check and to your departure gate.

You will claim your checked baggage and pass through Customs in Copenhagen. You will not need to claim baggage in Zurich.

Comment: Thank you was getting a bit worried as its such a short change over before we get the next onward flight

Comment: @palmy Zurich is a fairly small airport. You shouldn't have a problem. But even if you do, your airline is responsible for getting you to your destination.

Comment: Zürich is the 16th airport in Europe (passengers) with 1/3 of the passengers of Heathrow (the busiest in Europe): not so small ...

Comment: And Intercontinental flights arrive at Terminal E, while Schengen flights depart from A or B. OP will have to take the shuttle train.

Comment: @Matteo Right, I've incorporated this information.

Comment: The order of things listed by you is wrong. See my answer

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is correct: you clear immigration in Zurich.

However, the order listed is wrong. Follow the signs to the A/B gates, and you will:

1. Clear security.
2. Take the escalator down to the underground Skymetro train, which takes you to immigration.
3. Clear immigration
4. Visit the transfer desk if necessary.
5. Go to the gate